# How to use a separate CSS file with elm?

Tags: css, elm

Is the only way to use an external stylesheet with Elm to use [Browser.element](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser#element)  and do something like the following?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="spectre.min.css">
    <script src="elm.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="elm-app-is-loaded-here"></div>
    <script>
      var app = Elm.Main.init({
        node: document.getElementById("elm-app-is-loaded-here")
      });      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What if I want to use a [Browser.Document](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser#document) instead, or even a [Browser.Application](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser#application) ?

When searching the internet for Elm and CSS, I only find libraries that write CSS using Elm, or that replace CSS with Elm code. But what if I already have a CSS stylesheet that I want to use. I'd like to use Spectre CSS. It's just a single CSS file "spectre.min.css". Can I use that with Elm in a simple way?

Comment: You'd still do it the exact same way. [`elm-spa-example`](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-spa-example), for example, uses `Browser.application`. The different `Browser` functions just allows more interaction with the document as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to learn that Browser.Document keeps the stylesheet that is given in the head tag, and that it just replaces the body and the title, without modifying the rest. And thanks for the github elm-spa-example. I'm learning a lot by reading the source of that example.

Comment: It's problematic because, although in principle it's possible to add an external file that way, it's very inconvenient during development: I can't find any way to add a custom CSS file with elm reactor, or with elm-live. Is it really impossible to use a custom CSS file during development?

Comment: Ok it's actually possible with elm-live but I needed to read the following Github issue, and especially the last message (otherwise you get an "ERROR IN COMMAND" message) https://github.com/wking-io/elm-live/issues/133

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the HTML document (i.e. the `head` section) where your app is running in then you have to switch from using `elm-reactor` to embedding the compiled Elm app like [described in the Elm guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/#embedding-in-html).

I have created a [little boilerplate setup](https://github.com/axelerator/elm-nano-examples/tree/master/hot_elm) that allows me to control the "`index.html`" and have hot code reloading via a little script (no other dependencies).